# I'm adapting CMU Sphinx for my native language, and want to write a demo that uses just a couple of words. is there any way to do so?

Tags: speech-recognition

How about not writing an engine, but using existing one and train it for, like, 5 words from my native language?

Comment: have you found your need...i am also looking for the same...can you post your answer if find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with CMUSphinx speech recognition engine. For example you can adapt existing English model to words of your language using phoneset mapping. It works pretty well. For details see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt